# Process start duration between Python3 and Python2

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I observe a significant time delta for starting a serie of processes between Python **3.5** and Python **2.7**.

In this below code, if CRITICAL = 8 : perf are almost identical in Py2 and Py3 (<1s). But for 9+, perf in Py2 remains unchanged whereas in Py3 it goes deeply worst (~1min!).

It seems linked to the size of args i give to process...

***UPDATE :***  it's also linked to the location of module. Indeed, if it's run from "C:\" (or short path), then Py3 is similar to Py2. But if run from very long path, perf in Py3 are very downgraded, whereas it remains unchanged in Py2.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from multiprocessing import Process
import time
import itertools


def workerTask(inputs):
    for _ in itertools.product(*inputs):
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    CRITICAL = 9  # OK for 8-, KO for 9+
    start = time.time()
    ARGS = [["123.4567{}".format(i) for i in range(CRITICAL)] for _ in range(10)]
    workerPool = [Process(target=workerTask, args=(ARGS,)) for _ in range(15)]
    for idx, w in enumerate(workerPool):
        print("...Starting process #{} after {}".format(idx + 1, time.time() - start))
        w.start()
    print("ALL PROCESSES STARTED in {}!".format(time.time() - start))
```

Comment: can you run the same example code using the unix `time` command? Can you rework your code so that one can execute it and reproduce the issue? Tx!

Comment: @Vince this snippet needs heavy reworking to run with all this `self` and missing imports. Please provide a [mcve] or you won't get any answer...

Comment: I will try to do a minimal example but before doing this i was wondering if there was something i did not know in python3 explaining this delta time with same code.

Comment: this isn't a [mcve] even with your last edit. you don't need `SCRIPTS_LOCATION = r"Y:\VSA_SANDBOX\DRAFT"
NB_CMD_PER_SCRIPT = 50000
INPUT_DATA = ["0:DUMMY_COMMAND SUB_COMMAND",` ... running as is crashes because SCRIPTS_LOCATION doesn't exist, except on your machine :)

Comment: Yes, i finally stretch code to find out it seems linked to size of args provided to process... it has no impact on Py2 but seems significantly sizing for Py3...

Comment: OK, it seems linked to location of module.
Indeed, if i run it from "C:\TEST", time to run in Py3 is OK, as in Py2.
But if i run from "C:\U:\TEST_ABCDEFGHABCDEFGHABCDEFGH_ABCDEFGHABCDEFGHABC_DEFGHABCDEFGHABCD_EFGHABCDEFGHABCDEFGHAAAAAA_AAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBCCC_CCCCCCCCCCCCCCC_CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC", time to run in Py3 is KO, whereas it remains OK in Py2!

Comment: Just curious what means KO? Have never seen this abbreviation before

Comment: sorry (KO = not OK), just want to say time to run in Py3 in this location is far higher than in root location.

Comment: Well maybe this is because the main difference between Py2 and Py3 is in representation of text strings, and especially filesystem paths. Progress comes with a price tag. Py2 is simpler, smaller, leaner and it is not going to die.

Answer (score 1):

I've found an alternative, which seems very modular to "multi-process" works.
By this way, in Py3, time to launch N process remains similar to Py2.

Instead of providing huge args to each process, i create a shared object, linked to BaseManager, in which one i store huge data needed by process.
Furthemore, i can also store shared progress or any data computed by each process to continue after and use it. I really like this solution.

Here the code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import time
import itertools
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager


def workerTask(sharedSandbox):
    inputs = sharedSandbox.getARGS()
    for _ in itertools.product(*inputs):
        pass


class _SharedData(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.__myARGS = data

    def getARGS(self):
        return self.__myARGS


class _GlobalManager(BaseManager):
    BaseManager.register('SharedData', _SharedData)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    CRITICAL = 9  # OK for 8-, KO for 9+
    start = time.time()
    manager = _GlobalManager()
    manager.start()
    ARGS = manager.SharedData([["123.4567{}".format(i) for i in range(CRITICAL)] for _ in range(10)])
    workerPool = [Process(target=workerTask, args=(ARGS,)) for _ in range(15)]
    for idx, w in enumerate(workerPool):
        print("...Starting process #{} after {}".format(idx + 1, time.time() - start))
        w.start()
    print("ALL PROCESSES STARTED in {}!".format(time.time() - start))
    while any([w.is_alive() for w in workerPool]):
        pass
```